# boost for android in windows w/ cygwin - error while loading shared libraries

Tags: android, boost, android-ndk

I downloaded the boost library for android from [here](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android), but an error occurs at compile time:

```
/bjam.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

System info - ndk version: ndk-r8
os: Windows 7 64bit, cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, you are missing 
1a. some dependency
1b. bjam is conflicting with already placed bjam in your directory.

Else..

2. Try with http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2011/05/tips-tricks-building-boost-with-ndk-r5/
3. or refer [Official "Boost library" Support for Android and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036311/official-boost-library-support-for-android-and-ios/14054565#14054565)