# Building Boost Library on Mac OS for Android

Tags: android, macos, boost, build

I am following the documentation in https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android

I ran into issues while building it on Mac OS. Is there a documentation for how to do build boost on Mac OS for Android using ndk?

Comment: can you please tell the errors you are getting? also which mac os x you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)
Which issues? Did you face issues while compilation?
Are you using NDK 8rc ? If yes, then please check include and library path details mentioned in user configuration DOESNOT match with the NDK PATH

Check the following include path and update it as per the NDK path

-I$(ANDROID_NDK)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include

-I$(ANDROID_NDK)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi/include

Once you update this path, you will not get the errors.

(2)
In Following site https://github.com/mevansam/cmoss, he has compiled on mac os x.

(3)
Else you may refer this post [Official "Boost library" Support for Android and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036311/official-boost-library-support-for-android-and-ios) for alternatives.